# Gulp выполнение таска при добавлении файла

Tags: gulp

Привет. Нужно, чтобы при добавлении нового scss файла в каталог выполнялся таск 'scss'. Что у мен не так?

```js
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglifyjs'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    csso = require('gulp-csso'),
    streamqueue  = require('streamqueue'),
    svgSprite = require("gulp-svg-sprites"),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    reload = browserSync.reload,
    argv = require('yargs').argv,
    shell = require('gulp-shell'),
    jade = require('gulp-jade'),
    svgo = require('gulp-svgo'),
    spritesmith = require('gulp.spritesmith'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject-string'),
    livereload = require('gulp-livereload');


var src = {
    scss: 'src/**/*.scss',
    html: '**/*.html',
    script:"src/js/**/*.js",
    jade: "src/**/*.jade",
};

// Компиляция Sass файлов в файл style.css
gulp.task('sass', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({outputStyle: 'normal'}).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'safari 5', 'ie 8', 'ie 9', 'opera 12.1', 'ios 6', 'android 4'],
            cascade: false
        }))
    .pipe(csso())
    .pipe(concat('compile.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/css'))
    .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});
//сборка css в единый bunlde.css
gulp.task('css-build', function() {
  return gulp.src("./src/css/**/*.css")
    .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
    .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});

//сборка всех файлов из jslib в единый all.js
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return streamqueue({ objectMode: true },
        gulp.src('./src/js/jquery-3.2.1.js'),
        gulp.src('./src/js/slick.js'),
        gulp.src('./src/js/sprite.js'),
        gulp.src('./src/js/slick-set.js'),
        gulp.src([
            './src/js/**/*.js',
            '!./src/js/jquery-3.2.1.js',
            '!./src/js/slick.js',
            '!./src/js/sprite.js',
            '!./src/js/slick-set.js'
        ])
    )
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'))
    .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});

//сборка SVG спрайта
gulp.task('svg-sprites', function () {
    return gulp.src(['./src/blocks/**/*.svg', './src/img/**/*.svg'])
        .pipe(svgSprite({
         mode: "symbols",
            preview: false
        }))
        .pipe(concat('sprite.svg'))
        //.pipe(svgo())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./dist/img"))
        .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});

//jade компилятор
gulp.task('jade', function() {

  return gulp.src(['./src/**/*.jade', '!./src/blocks/**/*.jade', '!./src/include.jade'])
  .pipe(jade())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'))
  .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});

//сборка png спрайта
gulp.task('sprite-png', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src(['./src/blocks/**/*.png', './src/img/**/*.png']).pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'sprite.png',
    cssName: 'sprite-png.css',
    imgOpts: {quality: 95},
    algorithm: 'left-right'
  }));
  return spriteData.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img'))
  .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});

//сборка jpg спрайта
gulp.task('sprite-jpg', function () {
  var spriteData = gulp.src(['./src/blocks/**/*.jpg','./src/blocks/**/*.jpeg', './src/img/**/*.jpg','./src/img/**/*.jpeg']).pipe(spritesmith({
    imgName: 'sprite.jpg',
    cssName: 'sprite-jpg.css',
    imgOpts: {quality: 95},
    algorithm: 'left-right'
  }));
  return spriteData.pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/img'))
  .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});

//Переном шрифтов
gulp.task('font-transfer', function () {
  return gulp.src('./src/fonts/**/*.*')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/fonts'))
  .pipe(livereload({stream:true}));
});

//gulp wath - функция которая смотрит за изменениями всех используемых в проекте файлов и если какой-либо файл был изменен, то перезапускает необходимую gulp задачу для сборки этого файла
gulp.task('watch',['sass', 'scripts', 'jade', 'sprite-png', 'sprite-jpg', 'css-build'], function() {
livereload.listen();
 gulp.watch('./src/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
   gulp.watch('./src/js/**/*.js', ['scripts']);
    gulp.watch('./src/img/*.svg', ['svg-sprites']);
     gulp.watch('./src/**/*.jade', ['jade']);
      gulp.watch('./src/blocks/**/*.png', ['sprite-png']);
       gulp.watch('./src/blocks/**/*.jpg', ['sprite-jpg']);
        gulp.watch('./src/css/**/*.css', ['css-build']);
});

// сервер browser-sync

gulp.task('server', ['sass', 'scripts', 'watch', 'svg-sprites', 'jade', 'sprite-png', 'sprite-jpg', 'font-transfer', 'css-build'], function() {

    browserSync.init({
        proxy:'localhost/snapjs',
        port:3000
    });

    gulp.watch(src.scss, ['sass']);
    gulp.watch(src.jade).on('change', reload);
});

//создание и удаление bem блоков
gulp.task('bem', function () {
     if (argv.create) {
        return gulp.src('./src/include.jade')
         .pipe(inject.append('include blocks/'+argv.create+'/'+argv.create+'\n'))
         .pipe(concat('include.jade'))
         .pipe(gulp.dest('./src'))
          .pipe(shell([
            'cd ./src/blocks&&mkdir '+argv.create+
            '&&cd '+argv.create+
            '&&touch '+argv.create+'.jade &&touch '+argv.create+'.scss &&mkdir img'
          ]))
    }
     if (argv.remove) {
        return gulp.src('./src/include.jade')
          .pipe(shell([
            'cd ./src/blocks&&rm -rf '+argv.remove+'',
            'sed -i /'+argv.remove+'/d src/include.jade'
          ]))
    }
    console.log(find);
});

gulp.task('dev', ['sass', 'scripts', 'watch', 'svg-sprites', 'jade', 'sprite-png', 'sprite-jpg', 'font-transfer']);

gulp.task('default', ['dev']);
```

Comment: попробуй `gulp.watch` заменить на `watch`

Comment: Нет, не помогает.